# Delete lines with particular number of columns in linux

Tags: bash, unix

My file.fam looks like following containing around 22k lines. I want to delete rows containing less than 6 columns.

```
06S14031708 36125 0 0 2 2
06S14031716 38824 0 0 1 2
06S14031729 27949 0 0 2 2
06S14031742 30585 0 0 2 2
5 5 0 0 1 1
6 6 0 0 1 
12 12 0 0 1 2
16 16 0 0 1 2
18_0004 21213 0 0 1 1
18_0006 35931 0 0 1 1
18_0008 31975 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Do you want to delete `1 2 3 4  6` (two spaces, an empty column)? When you want to keep this one, a simple `awk` solution will fail.

Comment: @WalterA: I would not agree with that. Andrej's suggestion would also work with it in my opinion.

Comment: @Cyrus: My point is that my example has 6 columns when you consider a single space as a separator. The fifth column exists and is empty. `echo "1 2 3 4  6" | awk 'NF >= 6'` doesn't print the inputline with 6 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` version redirecting all lines w/ more than 5 "words" to a new file:

```
awk 'NF>=6' file.fam > file.fam.new
mv file.fam.new file.fam
```

Or a somewhat more unsightly variant using `sed` with inline replacement:

```
sed -i -r '/^\s*(\w+\s+){5}\w+\s*$/!d' file.fam
```